# Tear down method for twisted reactor?

Tags: python, twisted

I'm writing a custom reactor for twisted and it needs some cleaning to do when it has to stop.
I tried overriding the stop method like this:

```
def stop(self):
    posixbase.PosixReactorBase.stop(self)
    #cleanup code here
```

It does, however, seem to **not** always be called. When I run trial like this `python -m cProfile /usr/bin/trial -r custom tests/ | grep "stop"` the only *stop* methods that are called are:

```
    2    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 abstract.py:397(stopReading)
    1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 abstract.py:405(stopWriting)
    1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 log.py:691(stop)
    1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 protocol.py:678(stopProtocol)
    3    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 reporter.py:97(stopTest)
    3    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 result.py:79(stopTest)
    1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 udp.py:218(stopListening)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't do this.  Don't subclass the reactor, don't override methods on it.  If you want to run code when the reactor stops, use `reactor.addSystemEventTrigger("before", "shutdown", f)` (or `"during"` shutdown or `"after"` shutdown).

Or use a higher level API and define a [`Service`](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/api/twisted.application.service.Service.html) with a `stopService` method and hook your service up to the [`application`](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/core/howto/application.html).